# .net core 5 Web API serialize object with elements as attributes

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

If I have enabled xml serialization in a .net 5 web api:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
        .AddJsonOptions(o => 
        {
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        });

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "DemoService", Version = "v1" });
    });
}
```

What xml serializer/deserializer does it use and how can I control if an object property gets serialized as an attribute vs element?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you can decorate a class property with attribute.
For example, we have a class named Book. And we want to display the id as an xml attribute and the title as an xml element:

```
public class Book
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

The xml produced looks like that:

```
 <ArrayOfBook xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Book Id="1">
        <Title>Book 1</Title>
    </Book>
    <Book Id="2">
        <Title>Book 2</Title>
    </Book>
  </ArrayOfBook>
```

Comment: I think the XmlAttribute and XmlElement are used by the XmlSerializer.  I don't think that serializer is used by the .net 5 web api